# Accessing a variable within a passed object

Tags: java

I'm having issues with a concept from an assignment I'm working on

```
public class MyHugeInteger
{

MyIntList list = new MyIntList();

    public int compareTo(MyHugeInteger hugeInt)
    {
        if (list.size() > this.list.size()) //this is where things don't work
            return (-1);
        if (list.size() < this.list.size())
            return (1);
    }
```

Basically, I need to be able to use the 'list' variable from the passed version of the object to be able to compare it to the list variable from the current object.

I had a similar problem to this before, and my professor responded with "objects of the same class can access each others' private data members. So you do have access to other.size from "this" and can check Set sizes for equality."

This is what I'm trying to use in the code given, but I found an example saying that this will call the field variable, the one already called by just saying 'list'

Am I missing something?

Comment: change to `hugeInt.list.size() > this.list.size()`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use the Java framework to sort things or use the compareTo method, as intended, you  need to `implements Comparable<MyHugeInteger>` in your class.

```
public class MyHugeInteger implements Comparable<MyHugeInteger>
```

Then, to fix the error, you need to use the parameter object because `this.list` and the unqualified `list` are the exact same  object.

Also consider what happens when sizes are equal.

Tip: don't need to rewrite the integer comparison logic yourself.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(MyHugeInteger hugeInt) {
    return Integer.compare(this.list.size(), hugeInt.list.size());
}
```

Multiply by negative one or flip the parameters if you notice the ordering is wrong.

Comment: You're still using this.list.size() which is where I'm having the problem

writing the integer comparison logic is part of the assignment, and also not part of the question I asked

Comment: I don't understand. Yes, I'm using it... That's not the issue. You have to use the parameter... This answer works, but the other answer is that `list.size() == this.list.size()` always.

Comment: Comparison between huge integer and a list of integer doesn't rely to the size... This answer is as false as the question...

Comment: @Aubin What's your issue? If my answer is wrong, the question isn't complete, and that's not my problem

Comment: My confusion stemmed from my prof's comment, I thought that 'this' would refer to the passed object and not the current class (IE this.list = list) I was massively overthinking it

Comment: Yeah, `this` always means "this instance of this class"

Answer (score 0):

The comment was right, hugeInt.list.size() > this.list.size() instead of using 'this' for the passed object. One of those things that you miss when you're overthinking the problem

Comment: My answer uses that same logic, by the way